# Undefined method "id" trying to save nested attributes in the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-attributes

I am developing a web application with Rails in which I need to save two models with the same form. One of the models (Characteristic) belongs to the other (Facilities), so I decided to use a accepts_nested_attributes_for for the contained model. In the view, I use form_for to save the parent model (Characteristic) and another form_for for the contained model (Facilities). However, I always obtain the same error:

```
Started PUT "/facilities/537f8adfb4f2d7c124000056" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-31 20:00:23 +0200
Processing by FacilitiesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xr+cGlb9onx4o13IaS3K5UfYzmrb6pMdKljBc8byKdY=", "facilities"=>{"description"=>"Services", "characteristics"=>[{"id"=>"537f8adfb4f2d7c124000057", "title"=>"Room", "description"=>"Free"}]}, "commit"=>"Send", "id"=>"537f8adfb4f2d7c124000056"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (1.2872ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=hotel_abadi_development collection=facilities selector={"_id"=>"537f8adfb4f2d7c124000056"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4916ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=hotel_abadi_development collection=admins selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"537f8ad9b4f2d7c124000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7987ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=hotel_abadi_development collection=admins selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"537f8ad9b4f2d7c124000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7885ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=hotel_abadi_development collection=facilities selector={"$query"=>{"admin_id"=>"537f8ad9b4f2d7c124000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.8206ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 502.0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0xa6ae334>):
  app/controllers/facilities_controller.rb:21:in `update'


  Rendered /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered /home/jesus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (17.7ms)
```

In order to solve the problem, I have also tried to use fields_for with the nested attributes but I obtain the same error. The main files which defines the application are the next:

**app/models/facilities.rb**

```
class Facilities
  ...
  field :description, type: String
  field :language,    type: Symbol, default: :es

  has_many   :characteristics, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :characteristics, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

**app/models/characteristic.rb**

```
class Characteristic
  ...
  field :title,       type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :language,    type: Symbol, default: :es

  belongs_to :admin
  has_one    :upload, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :upload, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

**app/controllers/facilities_controller.rb**

```
class FacilitiesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  respond_to :json, :html
  ...
  def update
    @facilities.update_attributes!( params[:facilities] )
    respond_with @facilities, api_template: :general, location: hotel_path
  end
  ...
end
```

**app/views/facilities.html.haml**

```
= form_for facilities, url: facilities_path( facilities ) do |f|
  = f.text_area :description
  .facilities_form
    - facilities.characteristics.each_with_index do |char, index|
      = form_for characteristic, url: characteristic_path( characteristic ), html: { method: :put } do |d|
        = d.hidden_field :id, name: 'facilities[characteristics][][id]'
        = d.text_field :title, width: 20, size: 20, name: 'facilities[characteristics][][title]'
        = d.text_area :description, width: 20, rows: 4, cols: 22, name: 'facilities[characteristics][][description]'

  = f.submit "Send"
```

---

**Solved:**

In the nested attributes, I manually put the name of the fields because I am using another form_for for them. In that names, I use "facilities[**characteristics**][][name_of_field]", but when we need to use nested attributes, we have to put "characteristics_attributes", so the correct name is "facilities[**characteristics_attributes**][][name_of_field]".

Comment: The full backtrace would be helpful.

Comment: I have puts the full backtrace. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted that you use facilities instead of facility both in view and controller.
I assume the problem is `load_and_authorize_resource` in `FacilitiesController` try to load `@facility` extracting `id` from `params`. So, change `facilities_path( facilities )` to `facilities_path(@facility)` or something similar.

Comment: In the view, I use lots of partials. In order to simplify the code in the question, I only put the main code of the view and I forget to use @facilities. The model is Facilities, not Facility. Thanks.